# How to send XML PUT request via Java Code

Tags: java, xml, web-services, http, soap

There is a REST web service on my project.
I tried to use Restlet Client(extension for Google Chrome) for sending XML PUT request.
And i received 200 OK success.
Now i want to send the same XML PUT request to web service, but via JAVA CODE.

1st solution:
I used HttpClient from Apache but it returns org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: failed to respond

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String url = "SECRET";

    //CONFIGS
    String ip = "127.0.0.1";
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(ip, 1080);
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
    HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
    put.setConfig(config);

    //HEADER SECTION
    put.setHeader("SourceApplication","application");
    put.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

    //BODY SECTION
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company","VALUE1"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company2","VALUE2"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company3","VALUE3"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company4","VALUE4"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company5","VALUE5"));
    urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company6","VALUE6"));

    put.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));


    //PRINT REQUEST
    String uri = put.getRequestLine().getUri();
    System.out.println(uri);
    BufferedReader bd = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(put.getEntity().getContent()));
    StringBuffer rs = new StringBuffer();
    String line = "";
    while ((line = bd.readLine()) != null) {
        rs.append(line);
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    //EXECUTE REQUEST
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
    System.out.println("Response Code : "
    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

    //PRINT RESPONSE
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    String line1 = "";
    while ((line1 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line1);
        System.out.println(line1);
    }
}
```

}

**RESPONSE**

```
org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: failed to respond
```

2nd solution:
I tried to use SOAP.
But SOAP allows to send only GET and POST methods.(i need to send PUT method).
When i send my xml via POST method. Response returns 405 Method not allowd.

```
public class CompanyCreationScript {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
        SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();

        System.setProperty("socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1");
        System.setProperty("socksProxyPort", "1080");

        String url = "SECRET";
        SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(), url);

        printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

        soapConnection.close();
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.err.println("Error occurred while sending SOAP Request to Server");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private static SOAPMessage createSOAPRequest() throws Exception {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    String serverURI = "http://www.wktransportservices.com/schema/mbs/wktsadmin/companyuseraddress/v1_13";

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("exmaple", serverURI);

    SOAPBody soapBody = envelope.getBody();
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem = soapBody.addChildElement("VerifyEmail", "example", "uri");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem1 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("email", "example");
    soapBodyElem1.addTextNode("mutantninja@gmail.com");
    SOAPElement soapBodyElem2 = soapBodyElem.addChildElement("LicenseKey", "example");
    soapBodyElem2.addTextNode("123");

    MimeHeaders headers = soapMessage.getMimeHeaders();
    headers.addHeader("SOAPAction", serverURI + "VerifyEmail");

    soapMessage.saveChanges();

    System.out.println("Request SOAP Message = ");
    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

    return soapMessage;
}

private static void printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
    TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
    Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
    System.out.println("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
    StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
    transformer.transform(sourceContent, streamResult);
}
```

}

Comment: this is the client do you have the server side implementation? looks like the server is not answering your request~

Comment: I tried to send XML PUT Request to Server via Restlet (Google Chrome extension) and it works! I received 200 status code Success! Server is ok!

Comment: Can you debug line by line? I don't know where can be the problem. I looks like the connection is disconnected. Which version of HttpClient are you using?

Comment: Exception thrown here: "        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);"
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException:  failed to respond

Comment: Ok now we know is in the execute so we have 2 main options. The `put` object is not well configured or the HTTPClient is not handling the response or not sending the request.

Comment: I post an update please check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use okhttpclient. Below is the sample code.

```
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://www.foo.bar/index.php")
    .put(xml)  // Use PUT on this line.
    .build();

Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
```

Comment: It won't work, XML can not be a string, you need to create a RequestBody object for it.

Answer (score 0):

**New UPDATE**
Can you try this header? and move the `setConfig` after adding the header.

```
put.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
put.addHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
put.addHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
put.setConfig(config);
```

This is an alternative:

```
StringEntity params = new StringEntity(data,"UTF-8");
params.setContentType("application/xml");
request.addHeader("Content-type", "application/xml");
request.addHeader("Accept", "*/*");
request.setEntity(params);
put.setConfig(config);
```

**UPDATE**

Assuming you're using HTTPClient of 4.1.3 or greater -

When constructing an entity, we have the option to specify the content being used for the POST or PUT operation for certain entities. There is a `ContentType` object which should be used to specify this by using the factory method `.create()` and specifying the `mimetype` with a `charset`. The `ContentType` will be used by the framework to properly emit the header in question:

```
ContentType.create("application/vnd.oma-pcc+xml", CharSet.forName("UTF-8"));
```

**NOTE** HttpClient 4.1.2

In the case of 4.1.2, when you create your entity for the post or put operation, set the content type on the entity not the execution (`HttpPost` or `HttpPut`) using `setContentType(String)`. This is deprecated in 4.1.3 and beyond.

Can you use this code to find the error, please:

```
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Start {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String url = "SECRET";

    //CONFIGS
    String ip = "127.0.0.1";
    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(ip, 1080);
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setProxy(proxy).build();
    try {
        HttpPut put = new HttpPut(url);
        put.setConfig(config);

        //HEADER SECTION
        put.setHeader("SourceApplication","application");
        put.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");

        //BODY SECTION
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company","VALUE1"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company2","VALUE2"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company3","VALUE3"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company4","VALUE4"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company5","VALUE5"));
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("company6","VALUE6"));

        put.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParameters));


        //PRINT REQUEST
        String uri = put.getRequestLine().getUri();
        System.out.println(uri);
        BufferedReader bd = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(put.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer rs = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = bd.readLine()) != null) {
            rs.append(line);
            System.out.println(line);
        }

        //EXECUTE REQUEST
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(put);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

        responseCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200 || response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204) 
            //PRINT RESPONSE
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));

            StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
            String line1 = "";
            while ((line1 = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                result.append(line1);
                System.out.println(line1);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());

            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                    + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        }
    }catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("ex Code sendPut: " + ex);
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }

}
```

Comment: ex Code sendPut: org.apache.http.NoHttpResponseException: failed to respond

Comment: I think is the version of the HTTPClient.

Comment: I changed version of HTTPClient to 4.1.2 as you said. And RequestConfig class and HttpClientBuilder is not found. Request Config is needed for set Proxy( i need to use proxy). Any ideas?

Comment: No, you didn't told me your version so I gave two options. But,  I recommend you to use the latest version. If you update the version let me know.

Comment: I think the header is not accepted by the server therefore you don't receive any response.

Comment: I use 4.3.2 version of HTTPClient. respond: NoHttpResponseException: The target server failed to respond
When i try to use 4.1.2 version, setConfig method is not found, and Request Config also

Comment: Could you please update to the version **HTTPClient of 4.5.2**

Comment: Updated to 4.5.2. Issue still the same.